# Dataframe new column value based on both other column criteria and calculation from other column

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a df:

```
name  type   cost new
AB     B      1   0
CV     G      4   0 
54     B      31  0
AB     B      2   0
```

I'd like to re-assign the value of column "new" based on if the "name" column is a certain value and, if so, do a calculation based on the "cost" column.

However what I'm trying isn't working:

```
df.loc[(df['type']=='G'),'new] = df["cost"]*0.75
```

Basically if the type is 'G', then the new column should be the calculation above.

I'm getting: 'ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['new'] = np.where(df['type'].eq('G'), df.cost * 0.75, 0)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  name type  cost  new
0   AB    B     1  0.0
1   CV    G     4  3.0
2   54    B    31  0.0
3   AB    B     2  0.0
```

Or as an alternative:

```
df['new'] = df['type'].eq('G') * (df.cost * 0.75)
```

Note that in order to use where you must import numpy (`import numpy as np`).

Answer (score 0):

This is a correct way:

```
df['new'] = df.loc[df['type'] == 'G', 'cost'] * .75
df['new'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

You can also use the function `mask`:

```
df['new'] = df['new'].mask(df['type'] == 'G', df['cost'] * .75)
```